# An active access token must be used to query information about the current user-Graph api exception

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to update Facebook user status using Graph api. My code is

```
<?php 
    require 'facebook.php'; 
    $facebook = new Facebook(array( 
    'appId' =>'389694921095423',
    'secret' =>'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'cookie' => true
    )); 
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    echo($access_token);
    $me = null; 

    try 
    { 
        $uid = $facebook->getUser(); 
        $me = $facebook->api('/me'); 
        echo "Welcome User: " . $me['name'] . "<br />"; 
        //access permission
        $permissions_needed = array('publish_stream', 'read_stream', 'offline_access', 'manage_pages');
        foreach($permissions_needed as $perm) 
        {  
            if( !isset($permissions_list['data'][0][$perm]) || $permissions_list['data'][0][$perm] != 1 )
            {    
            $login_url_params = array(
                'scope' => 'publish_stream,read_stream,offline_access,manage_pages',         
                'fbconnect' =>  1,         
                'display'   =>  "page",         
                'next' => 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']      
                );    
            $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($login_url_params);   
            header("Location: {$login_url}");
            exit(); 
            }
        }
        //Access permission

        $post_id = $facebook->api("/$uid/feed", "post", array("message"=>"Hello World!")); 
        if(isset($post_id)) 
        {
            echo "A new post to your wall has been posted with id: $post_id"; 
        }
    } 
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
    { 
        echo($e); 
    } 
?>
```

The problem is that it shows a run time error like Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. I have generated the Access Tocken. Where i have to use that to remove this exception
Thanks in advance

Comment: _“I have generated the Access Tocken.”_ – where and _when_ did you create it? Sounds like you’re using an already expired token. You can use the debug tool to check if your token is still valid or not: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: That is because  $facebook->getUser() is return 0 , and the user is not login.

Answer (score 32):

Try changing the line:

```
$me = $facebook->api('/me');
```

to

```
$me = $facebook->api('/'.$uid);
```

Also try upgrading your sdk if you are not using the latest version and if you just upgraded the sdk and it caused the trouble, than you can try to downgrade the version and check.

Comment: well, this is facebook! bizare errors, and the biggest problem is that this error can be caused by a lot of others problems too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked for me! But still can't figure why is "/me" still standing on FB documentation?

Comment: So this is still valid? Because sometimes I get the error about the token and still cannot be sure. Why is the fb docs still using the me and what is the difference?

Comment: Well, /me is a special symbol used by facebook, to identify the current logged in user, it is similar to using the current logged in user id. You should actually try to debug the response that you get from facebook, that will help you locate the trouble more accurately.

Answer (score 5):

Clear your cache & cookies (if you are testing or developing application) 
and 
Please do as follow:-

```
try
{  
  $fb_user_info = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (Exception $ex)
{
  $facebook->destroySession();
  $params = array(
      'scope' => 'YOUR_PERMISSIONS',
      'redirect_uri' => 'YOUR_SITE_URL'
  );
  $fb_login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);  
  header("Location:" . $fb_login_url);
}
```

Comment: *sidenote:* remember to call `exit;` after `header('Location: $url');`

Comment: typo error in your side note: it should be header('Location: '. $url); we cannot use variable in single quotes or it should be in double quotes

Comment: Yes. It's a stupid typo. Thanks for reminder. ( can't edit though )