# want to get face profile picture getting an error

Tags: php

I am getting the below error when I try to get a user's Facebook profile picture using the PHP script. The below error is given:

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

using the Facebook API.

I can access a user's public info just fine. However, when I try to post info to their Facebook account is when I get the error.

I am using the following code:

```
if(!isset($this->fbconnect)){           
    require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'vendor/facebook-sdk/facebook.php');
    $this->fbconnect = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => '623704417744682',
        'secret' => 'b73816b90424ad47fd0f1c8f669b8324',
    ));
}

$user = $this->fbconnect->getUser();
if ($user <> '0' && $user <> '') { 
    /* if valid user id i.e. neither 0 nor blank nor null */
    try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $this->fbconnect->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) { 
        error_log($e);
        $user = '0';
    }
}

if ($user <> '0' && $user <> '') {
    /* So now we will have a valid user id with a valid oauth access token and so the code will work fine. */
    $user_profile = $this->fbconnect->api('/me');
    print_r($user_profile);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [An active access token must be used to query information about the current user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491737/an-active-access-token-must-be-used-to-query-information-about-the-current-user) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776234/an-active-access-token-must-be-used-to-query-information-about-the-current-user)

Comment: OK, and so you need an active access token...

Comment: Probably not a good idea to post your appid and secret in the question

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are asking 2 questions. To get their fb profile picture you need their fb userId. Then all you have to do is set your img source to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/".$userId."/picture"
```