# OAuthException : An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-oauth, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to run the sample code for Facebook connect that I downloaded from http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-3-0-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/
I get this error message :

```php
[error] => Array
            (
                [message] => An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
                [type] => OAuthException
                [code] => 2500
            )
```

You can try on my website : http://facebook.oliverjordan.net/thinkdiff

Here is the `fbmain.php` code :

```php
<?php

//facebook application
$fbconfig['appid' ]     = "463007877113xxx";
$fbconfig['secret']     = "-sensor-";
$fbconfig['baseurl']    = "http://facebook.oliverjordan.net/thinkdiff/index.php"; //"http://thinkdiff.net/demo/newfbconnect1/php/sdk3/index.php";

//
if (isset($_GET['request_ids'])){
    //user comes from invitation
    //track them if you need
}

$user            =   null; //facebook user uid
try{
    include_once "facebook.php";
}
catch(Exception $o){
    error_log($o);
}
// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
  'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
  'cookie' => true,
));

//Facebook Authentication part
$user       = $facebook->getUser();
// We may or may not have this data based 
// on whether the user is logged in.
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know 
// the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don’t know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.


$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope'         => 'email,offline_access,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_location,user_work_history,user_about_me,user_hometown',
            'redirect_uri'  => $fbconfig['baseurl']
        )
);

$logoutUrl  = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();


if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    //you should use error_log($e); instead of printing the info on browser
    d($e);  // d is a debug function defined at the end of this file
    $user = null;
  }
}


//if user is logged in and session is valid.
if ($user){
    //get user basic description
    $userInfo           = $facebook->api("/$user");

    //Retriving movies those are user like using graph api
    try{
        $movies = $facebook->api("/$user/movies");
    }
    catch(Exception $o){
        d($o);
    }

    //update user's status using graph api
    //http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/
    if (isset($_GET['publish'])){
        try {
            $publishStream = $facebook->api("/$user/feed", 'post', array(
                'message' => "I love thinkdiff.net for facebook app development tutorials. :)", 
                'link'    => 'http://ithinkdiff.net',
                'picture' => 'http://thinkdiff.net/ithinkdiff.png',
                'name'    => 'iOS Apps & Games',
                'description'=> 'Checkout iOS apps and games from iThinkdiff.net. I found some of them are just awesome!'
                )
            );
            //as $_GET['publish'] is set so remove it by redirecting user to the base url 
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            d($e);
        }
        $redirectUrl     = $fbconfig['baseurl'] . '/index.php?success=1';
        header("Location: $redirectUrl");
    }

    //update user's status using graph api
    //http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/
    if (isset($_POST['tt'])){
        try {
            $statusUpdate = $facebook->api("/$user/feed", 'post', array('message'=> $_POST['tt']));
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            d($e);
        }
    }

    //fql query example using legacy method call and passing parameter
    try{
        $fql    =   "select name, hometown_location, sex, pic_square from user where uid=" . $user;
        $param  =   array(
            'method'    => 'fql.query',
            'query'     => $fql,
            'callback'  => ''
        );
        $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
    }
    catch(Exception $o){
        d($o);
    }
}

function d($d){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($d);
    echo '</pre>';
}?>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [An active access token must be used to query information about the current user-Graph api exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776234/an-active-access-token-must-be-used-to-query-information-about-the-current-user)

Comment: still don't get the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must ensure that your access token is active. Or maybe you're in logout condition. Or try to clean the cookies and cache from your browser `(ctrl+shift+del)`

Comment: Is the user going to clean its cache ?

Answer (score 2):

Please check if you are getting any Facebook exceptions like

> An active access token must be used to query information about the
>   current user.

which causes  0 as user id in return from `$facebook->getUser()`.

So please check with `getAccessTokenFromCode()` from `base_facebook.php` and verify `access_token_response` format as it may be in JSON format.

So try to use appropriate decoding method to get `$response_params['access_token']` from `$access_token_response`.