# How to use curl or C++ code to ask Facebook users to access their Facebook wall?

Tags: c++, facebook, curl

I'm coding a C++ program,
I tried, using an external command, to launch that :

```
curl -F 'access_token=XXX' -F 'message=test' http://graph.facebook.com/me/feed
```

But I receive this error :

```
{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}
```

How should I invite users to accept that my application can access to their facebook wall and post a message on their own wall?

Comment: did you try the solution proposed here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801406/oauthexception-an-active-access-token-must-be-used-to-query-information-about

Comment: I'm not sure how to adapt this in C++, and also, I don't have any URL... (he uses 'baseurl')

Comment: I was talking about the solution proposed (clean the cache) http://stackoverflow.com/a/19697785/1393890

Comment: ah ok, yeah I tried it. Doesn't work